# C sharp : Window Installed application with their icon/logo?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have a project to build, where I need find some particular installed application on windows "With their specified Logo/icon".

e.g. Mozilla firefox with logo etc

I know two ways to check installed application.
1. to check particular exe, dll in specified folder.
2. check registry key.

Both ways work finally but it not displaying installed program with logo.

anybody have Idea how to do this?

Thanx

Comment: Do you have an image comparison handy which can account for different sizes, pixels differing with only a few RGB values away? Dude, this is totally crazy...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "with logo". Are you trying to *identify* the application based on its logo? Or simply *display* the logo once you've identified the application? Is a logo different from the executable's icon?

Comment: If u see windows add remove feature, it displays list of installed application with their default icons. That I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code project article [Extracting Icons from EXE/DLL and Icon Manipulation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/ExtractIcons.aspx). Author explained how to retrieve the logo from the exe.

Answer (score 0):

We can find information about icons of installed product from following location This information is stored in registry at Installer\product key also along with Uninstall-

Key name - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products{productID}

Value - ProductIcon

From here we can get the icons of installed application. For more detail 
http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2015/06/extract-icons-of-installed-windows_17.html